# Validate XML Schema 1.1 in Intellij IDEA

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd-1.1

I'm trying to validate in Intellij XML against an XML Schema 1.1. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the error that I'm getting. Already switched `Default XML Schemas` to `XML Schema 1.1`. What am I missing?

```sh
/Users/user/tools/git/testxmlxsd/app/src/main/res/xml/assertion/assertion.xsd
Error:(10, 39) s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_data' is invalid.  
Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Validating the XSD also doesn't work. Here the error:

```sh
Error:(936, 30) rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error:(936, 30) derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'all'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
```

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data min="5" max="10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="assertion.xsd"/>
```

**XSD**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    vc:minVersion="1.1" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="data" vc:minVersion="1.0" vc:maxVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:assert test="@min le @max"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186219) in IntelliJ IDEA. Please vote/comment.

Comment: Thanks, already did. So, is the only option to use XSD 1.0 for now? I have a plugin that'd greatly benefit from XSD 1.1 as it'll detect a bunch of issues on the client-side if XSD 1.1 were supported.